# Issue with Date type (OBJECT or NUMBER)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am using `react-datepicker` to handle date inputs and when i submit my form to my `Spring-Mvc` API, the date field is a javacript date object like below

[image]

And it get mapped (and saved into database with `JPA/Hibernate`) without problem in my spring bean

```
public class FooBean {

    ...
    public Date dateStart;
```

With my Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/foos")
public Integer saveFoos(@RequestBody FooBean bean) {
    return fooService.saveFoo(bean);
}
```

and the date field in the entity is mapped like this

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "date_os_start")
private Date dateStart;
```

But when i try to read the value from the database and send it to the client with the same `FooBean` (dto/json), the date value is a number like this :

[image]

And I got this Error

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `selected` of type `Number` supplied to `DatePicker`, 
expected instance of `Date`.
```

How can I get date from database in the same format as JavaScript date object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like when the date is saved to your database it's converted into a unix timestamp.

You would have to convert the unix timestamp back into a JS date object before passing it to whichever `react-datepicker` component you are using.

```
const date = new Date(1555372800000)
```

Comment: How can I do this automatically when i select date values from database ?

Comment: thanks man it works ... even if i wanted to do the work in server side with java but it's fine doing the conversion with JavaScript is good